# Magento 2.0 hosted on Google Cloud - Email/Smtp Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have no computer knowledge, so here under a message from my developer to you :

"All the email related problems are occurring because the server is not able to fire mail.
The smtp details you provided are ok and are working at our server well. But when we try to fire a mail using the given smtp details on your server it shows an error.This is the testing url for smtp mail http://kzdiffusion.fr/smtpmailertest/testemail.php

Please ask the hosting provider to resolve the issue.

After that we will create an extension to send mail through smtp"

Can you please help with that problem above, please ?

My project is already delayed 2 months. Every tips that can help moving forward is a big plus. Google Support is not answering my emails anymore.

Best Regards,
David.

Answer (score 0):

GCP blocks standard email ports , you can choose a non-standard port to send email through. You can also take advantage of the mail services offered by Compute Engine partners: SendGrid, Mailgun, and Mailjet.

See here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail